# SQL - Using COUNT in a SUM query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

OK so here is my Database

```
Patient(PatID, GName, FName, Suburb, PhNo InsurNo)  
Doctor(DocID, DocName, DocSpec, Cost)  
Appointment(AppID, AppTimeDate, PatID*, DocID*)  
Meds(MedID, MedName, Purpose, Admin, AppID*)  
Tests(TestID, TestName, TestResult, TestDate, PatID*)  
DocPat(PatID*, DocID*)
```

I am being asked to show the doctors name with the total cost of all appointments greater than average.

so far I have:

```
SELECT d.DocName, sum((NO_OF_APPS)*DocCost)    
from doctor d, (select count(AppID) as NO_OF_APPS  
                from appointment  
                group by DocID)  
group by DocName;
```

trying to use sum(count(appID)*DocCost) i know i am coming at this from the wrong angle can anyone shed some light?

Have made corrective adjustments:

```
SELECT d.DocName, d.docCost*COUNT(ap.AppID) as totalCost  
from doctor d  
left join appointment ap on ap.DocID=d.DocID  
GROUP BY d.DocID  
ORDER BY d.DocName  
HAVING totalCost > AVG(totalCost);
```

receiving '00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended' on Oracle SQL developer V4

Comment: in question mark correct DB you use, not all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join instead of subselects, it is much clearer and usually works faster. To analyze aggregation results you can use HAVING clause. Here is an example:

```
SELECT d.DocName, d.Cost*COUNT(a.AppID) as totalCost
from doctor d
left join appointment a on a.DocID=d.DocID
GROUP BY d.DocName
HAVING d.Cost > average(d.Cost);
ORDER BY d.DocName
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, as i disregarded the average. But note that the average here is based on DocCost - and instead it should be the average of total cost

Comment: That's probably true, i'm afraid I didn't understood everything right. Fixing it should be easy though, e.g. HAVING totalCost > average(totalCost). Am I right?

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help! I have made these adjustments and not much luck yet... getting invalid identifier for totalCost. SELECT d.DocName, d.docCost*COUNT(ap.AppID) as totalCost
from doctor d
left join appointment ap on ap.DocID=d.DocID
GROUP BY d.DocID
HAVING totalCost > AVG(totalCost);

Comment: so as instructed above i put 'HAVING totalCost > AVG(totalCost);' in line 5 and receiving an error "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Could you post your whole query? Which SQL do you use?

Comment: @Niemand, please find more info posted above. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't really test it by myself now, try changing GROUP BY GROUP BY d.DocID   to GROUP BY d.DocName, add Having BEFORE order by (look at my updated code).